# Android/java Cant read from .txt file in local storage

Tags: java, android, file-io, bufferedreader, internal-storage

So i have a .txt file in local storage its a simple text file. The text is basically just a series of lines.

I am using the code below to attempt to read the text file (i verify the file exists before calling this method).

```
public static String GetLocalMasterFileStream(String Operation) throws Exception {

//Get the text file
    File file = new File("sdcard/CM3/advices/advice_master.txt");
    if (file.canRead() == true) {System.out.println("-----Determined that file is readable");}

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        System.out.println("-----" + line);   //for producing test output
        text.append('\n');

    }
    br.close();
    System.out.print(text.toString());
    return text.toString();

}
```

The code produces in the log

> ----Determined that file is readable
>   But that is the ONLY output the file data is not written to the log

Also i have tried inserting before the while loop  the following to attempt to just read the first line

```
 line = br.readLine();
 System.out.println("-----" + line);
```

That produces the following output:

> -----null

Answer (score 0):

Check this out [getExternalStorage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

```
     File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
     File file = new File(path, "textfile.txt");
//text file is copied in sdcard for example
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a lead slash in file path  /sdcard/CM3/advices/advice_master.txt

```
 File file = new File("/sdcard/CM3/advices/advice_master.txt");
```

Comment: added the leading slash and it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just pass the txt file name as a parameter...

```
public void readFromFile(String fileName){
    /*
    InputStream ips;
    ips = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    //reading
    try{
        InputStreamReader ipsr = new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ipsr);
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            //reading goes here ;)
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
   */
// or try this
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
   }


}
```

Comment: works for me, but you can try another variant, I have added other variant also

Comment: I tried your varient and it did not work. but i saw your comment about it working for you. so i created a different file called test.txt with 3 lines in it, placed it the root of both the sd card and the local storage and it worked .

I did some testing and discovered that Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); actually points to the internal storage of the device not the SD card.

 Anyway i then replaced the new file with the old file and it did not work. I then went back to my ORIGONAL code pointed it to the new txt file and it worked. The issue was the .txt file its self

Comment: The txt file was generated using the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504024/android-java-copying-text-file-from-url-to-local-file-cannot-get-endline-chars?noredirect=1#comment56750228_34504024

with the exception that  bw.write(inputLine.toString());
was changed to bw.write(inputLine + "\r\n");

It provides the correct output if you open the file in wordpad (visually) but for what ever reason the file has problems being read back

Answer (score 0):

Let me refine my answer. You can try another way to read all lines from advice_master.txt and see what happens. It makes sure that all file contents can be read.

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");
try {
  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(YOUR_PATH), charset);

  for (String line : lines) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Ok i tried your suggestion and i got the following java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/storage/sdcard/CM3/advices/advice_master.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

The file path is correct because when i change it to something else it does throw the file not found error which is not present with the file path i was using